# OC call one swift function which returns an int array, but can not accept its element with an int variable

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsarray

I write a swift function which return an int array and call it in objective-c. But i can not assign the element of the return array to an int variable. (TotalRoute is an int array in swift)

This is the function in class GetRoute

```
func returnTotalRouteX()->[Int]{
    println("call returnTotalRouteX")
    var routeX = [Int]()
    for item in totalRoute{
        routeX.append(nodeData[item]!.xPosition)
    }
    println(totalRoute)
    println(routeX)
    return routeX
}
```

Then i call this in objective-c

```
    GetRoute *h = [[GetRoute alloc] init];

if (h.returnTotalRouteX.count == 0) {
    NSLog(@"it is empty");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"%@",h.returnTotalRouteX);
    NSLog(@"%@",h.returnTotalRouteX[0]);
    NSLog(@"it is not empty");
}
```

I could only write NSLog(@"**%@**",h.returnTotalRouteX[0]);. If i write NSLog(@"**%d**",h.returnTotalRouteX[0]); or i assign h.returnTotalRouteX[0] to an int variable, the answer is not what i want. How can i get the int value?

Comment: Have you tried to unbox it, ie `[h.returnTotalRouteX[0] intValue]` ?

Comment: Yes! It works with your advice! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *unbox* the `NSNumber` into a primitive `int` by calling `numberWithInt`, so in your case that would be `[h.returnTotalRouteX[0] intValue]`. The reason it worked when you log with `%@` pattern is because it was calling its string formatter.

In OOP, *boxing* is the storage of a primitive type in a reference type. *Unboxing* is the opposite process.

Some languages, like C# for instance, provide boxing and/or unboxing capabilities automatically by convention. So the following is perfectly fine in C#:

```
int unBoxed = 420;
Object boxed = unBoxed;
int unUnBoxed = (int)unBoxed;
```

However, Objective-C does not do this for you. So the same in Objective-C looks like this:

```
int unBoxed = 420;
NSNumber *boxed = [NSNumber numberWithInt:unBoxed];
int unUnBoxed = [boxed intValue];
```